# Spring mvc bootstrap

Tags: mvc, spring, bootstrap

Galera é o seguinte eu tenho um registro que pego com o elemento select do bootstrap e seleciono ele e preciso colocar um botao para adicionar esse registro em uma tabela abaixo isso na mesma pagina onde fica o select e um botao adicionar, e preciso adicionar outros registros que é carregado no select
eu seleciono um por vez e clik no botao adicionar e ai é para ir adicionando dinamicamente em uma tabela abaixo onde deverar ter um botao remove na tabela
entao depois que eu selecionar os registros desejados terá um botao salvar para realmente salvar no banco
estou precisando de ajuda para fazer essa parte

Answer (score 0):

Sua dúvida é respondida com uma implementação em JQuery e um post em HTML para o Spring MVC tratar suas escolhas, mas não está de fato relacionado com Spring MVC nem com Bootstrap.

Ora, uma vez carregado seu `select` com os campos necessários, e um botão "Adicionar" ao lado deste, o valor escolhido será enviado a um `form` inicialmente vazio, que, quando submetido, envia os códigos escolhidos para a página responsável por tratá-los. Além é claro de inserir visualmente na tela para o usuário como feedback e removê-los do `select`.

```
<p>Para onde você quer ir?</p>
<select id="meu_select">
  <option value="1">Paris</option>
  <option value="2">Moscou</option>
  <option value="3">Roma</option>
  <option value="4">Viena</option>
</select>
<button onclick="minha_funcao();">Adicionar</button>

<p>Você já escolheu:</p>
<div id="escolhas">
  <!-- Inicialmente vazio! -->
</div>

<form id="meu_form" method="post" action="/pagina_responsavel.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Submeter escolhas">
</form>

<script>
function minha_funcao() {
  if($('#meu_select').val()) {
    // Adiciona no post uma variável que tem nome criado a partir do 
    // valor escolhido (id_...) e o valor escolhido
    $('#meu_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="id_' + 
      $('#meu_select').val() + '" value="' + $('#meu_select').val() + '">');

    // Adiciona na tela o valor escolhido
    $("#escolhas").append("<p>" + $('#meu_select option:selected').text() + "</p>");

    // Remove do select o valor escolhido
    $("#meu_select option[value=\""+$('#meu_select').val()+"\"]").remove();
  }
}

</script>
```

A maneira mais fácil de saber que valor(es) foi(foram) escolhido(s), é checar se para cada valor enviado para o `select` existe uma variável de post `id_value`, onde `value` é 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.